# NodeJS & RxJS: convert observables to nodeJs streams

Tags: node.js, rxjs

I would like to convert an RxJs Observable that emits data to a nodeJS stream so I can stream this data in chunks via a nodeJS application endpoint.

Is this even possible?

Pseudo code in a nodeJS router (obviously not working):

```
out.post('/data', [
    body().isArray(),
], (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        next(new RequestValidationFailedError(errors.array()[0]));
    }

    const observable = service.getData(req.context); 
    req.pipe(observable);
});
```

Comment: What is `service.getData`? Is it an http call or something else?

Comment: it is a combination of multiple http calls to different servers that are merged into one observable.

Comment: So the returned Observer is going to emit only one value or errors. Right?

Comment: it's actually polling several endpoints for refreshed data :) but yes, it will return a merged value ... which will be updated every x of time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using simply the `next` and `complete` functions of an Observer, something like

```
service.getData(req.context).subsribe({
  next: data => res.write(data),
  complete: () => res.end()
})
```

**UPDATE: managing clients dropping the connection**

If we want to terminate the Obserable stream in case the client drops the connection, we can unsubscribe from the Observable if the event `"close"` is emitted by the `http.Request`. The logic in this case would look like this

```
const subscription = service.getData(req.context).subsribe({
  next: data => res.write(data),
  complete: () => res.end()
})

req.on("close", function() {
  // request closed unexpectedly
  subscription.unsubscribe();
});
```

Comment: this doesn't return a response once the first one becomes available. it returns the final response only if you drop the connection.

Comment: According to the [node http documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback) the `write` method of `http.ServerResponse` should stream the response if called more than once (_"The first time response.write() is called, it will send the buffered header information and the first chunk of the body to the client. The second time response.write() is called, Node.js assumes data will be streamed, and sends the new data separately. That is, the response is buffered up to the first chunk of the body."_). But maybe I am missing something.

Comment: not sure. But through postman it doesn't work correctly. What's also not very good is that if the client drops the connection - the response is still being published (internally in the logs I mean)

Comment: You can manage clients dropping the connections unsubscribing the subscription. I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: thank you! This seem to be just what I needed. The only problem is that on the client side there is no support for json streams :D

Comment: This `write` method won't do justice. We need `pipe` for this specific task. `write` waits for the stream to finish and only then returns the result to the client

Comment: If I understand the [Node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback) right, the `write` method of HttpResponse actually streams the data to the client (_"The first time response.write() is called, it will send the buffered header information and the first chunk of the body to the client. The second time response.write() is called, Node.js assumes data will be streamed, and sends the new data separately. That is, the response is buffered up to the first chunk of the body."_).

Comment: it works perfectly after I added the content type of `application/stream+json` to response :) Thanks a billion for your help, but as I mentioned the client angular application can't seem to consume pure json streams so I would need to migrate to events or websockets :)

Comment: Websockets with Observables work great. You can [look at this article](https://medium.com/free-code-camp/reactive-thinking-how-to-design-a-distributed-system-with-rxjs-websockets-and-node-57d772f89260) where, among other things, an implementation of Websockets+Observables is described

Comment: thanks, but I tend more towards events if taking into account what could happen when configuring websockets on nginx.

Answer (score 0):

This is approximately what I use. I needed the conversion for type compliance.

As far as I know Observables don't start emitting data until subscribed. The code below subscribes right away and immediately starts pushing data.

```js
import { Readable } from 'stream';

/**
 * Convert an observable to a readable.
 */
function convertToReadable(observable: Observable<string>): Readable => {
    const readable = new Readable({
        // https://stackoverflow.com/q/74670330/4417769
        read() { }
    });

    observable.subscribe(
        (value: string): void => {
            readable.push(value);
        },
        (error: Error): void => {
            readable.destroy(error);
        },
        (): void => {
            // complete
            readable.push(null);
        }
    );

    return readable;
};
```