# Creating a Readable stream from emitted data chunks

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nodejs-stream

Short backstory: I am trying to create a `Readable` stream based on data chunks that are emitted back to my server from the client side with WebSockets. Here's a class I've created to "simulate" that behavior:

```js
class DataEmitter extends EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        super();

        const data = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'hello', 'world', 'abc', '123'];
        // Every second, emit an event with a chunk of data
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            this.emit('chunk', data.splice(0, 1)[0]);

            // Once there are no more items, emit an event
            // notifying that that is the case
            if (!data.length) {
                this.emit('done');
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, 1e3);
    }
}
```

In this post, the `dataEmitter` in question will have been created like this.

```js
// Our data is being emitted through events in chunks from some place.
// This is just to simulate that. We cannot change the flow - only listen
// for the events and do something with the chunks.
const dataEmitter = new DataEmitter();
```

Right, so I initially tried this:

```js
const readable = new Readable();

dataEmitter.on('chunk', (data) => {
    readable.push(data);
});

dataEmitter.once('done', () => {
    readable.push(null);
});
```

But that results in this error:

```
Error [ERR_METHOD_NOT_IMPLEMENTED]: The _read() method is not implemented
```

So I did this, implementing `read()` as an empty function:

```js
const readable = new Readable({
    read() {},
});

dataEmitter.on('chunk', (data) => {
    readable.push(data);
});

dataEmitter.once('done', () => {
    readable.push(null);
});
```

And it works when piping into a write stream, or sending the stream to my test API server. The resulting `.txt` file looks exactly as it should:

```
foobarbazhelloworldabc123
```

However, I feel like there's something quite wrong and hacky with my solution. I attempted to put the listener registration logic (`.on('chunk', ...)` and `.once('done', ...)`) within the `read()` implementation; however, `read()` seems to get called multiple times, and that results in the listeners being registered multiple times.

The Node.js documentation says [this](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#readable_readsize) about the `_read()` method:

> When readable._read() is called, if data is available from the resource, the implementation should begin pushing that data into the read queue using the this.push(dataChunk) method. _read() will be called again after each call to this.push(dataChunk) once the stream is ready to accept more data. _read() may continue reading from the resource and pushing data until readable.push() returns false. Only when _read() is called again after it has stopped should it resume pushing additional data into the queue.

After dissecting this, it seems that the consumer of the stream calls upon `.read()` when it's ready to read more data. And when it is called, data should be pushed into the stream. But, if it is not called, the stream should not have data pushed into it until the method is called again (???). So wait, does the consumer call `.read()` when it is ready for more data, or does it call it after each time `.push()` is called? Or both?? The docs seem to contradict themselves.

Implementing `.read()` on `Readable` is straightforward when you've got a basic resource to stream, but what would be the proper way of implementing it in this case?

And also, would someone be able to explain in better terms what the `.read()` method is on a deeper level, and how it should be implemented?

Thanks!

**Response to the answer:**

I did try registering the listeners within the `read()` implementation, but because it is called multiple times by the consumer, it registers the listeners multiple times.

Observing this code:

```js
const readable = new Readable({
    read() {
        console.log('called');

        dataEmitter.on('chunk', (data) => {
            readable.push(data);
        });

        dataEmitter.once('done', () => {
            readable.push(null);
        });
    },
});

readable.pipe(createWriteStream('./data.txt'));
```

The resulting file looks like this:

```
foobarbarbazbazbazhellohellohellohelloworldworldworldworldworldabcabcabcabcabcabc123123123123123123123
```

Which makes sense, because the listeners are being registered multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the only purpose of actually implementing the `read()` method is to only start receiving the chunks and pushing them into the stream when the consumer is ready for that.

Based on these conclusions, I've come up with this solution.

```js
class MyReadable extends Readable {
    // Keep track of whether or not the listeners have already
    // been added to the data emitter.
    #registered = false;

    _read() {
        // If the listeners have already been registered, do
        // absolutely nothing.
        if (this.#registered) return;

        // "Notify" the client via websockets that we're ready
        // to start streaming the data chunks.
        const emitter = new DataEmitter();

        const handler = (chunk: string) => {
            this.push(chunk);
        };

        emitter.on('chunk', handler);

        emitter.once('done', () => {
            this.push(null);
            // Clean up the listener once it's done (this is
            // assuming the #emitter object will still be used
            // in the future).
            emitter.off('chunk', handler);
        });

        // Mark the listeners as registered.
        this.#registered = true;
    }
}

const readable = new MyReadable();

readable.pipe(createWriteStream('./data.txt'));
```

But this implementation doesn't allow for the consumer to control when things are pushed. I guess, however, in order to achieve that sort of control, you'd need to communicate with the resource emitting the chunks to tell it to stop until the `read()` method is called again.